# How would I use information from .text

Tags: python, selenium

So I have created a simple bit of code that executes all the way through but after it outputs the Battle Report, I want to use the Health (afterbattle): NUMBER to decide whether or not to loop back through the code provided

```
driver.get("https://randomtextrpg.com") # Starting Page
time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_name("optionsearch").click() # Find Monsters
time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/div/div/button").click() # Attack Monster
time.sleep(1)

BattleReport = driver.find_element_by_id("reportResult") # Battle Report
print (BattleReport.text)
time.sleep(1)
```

As you can see, after Battle Report i've told it to print the outcome... which looks something like this:

```
Battle Report 16.11.2018 03:21
Winner: Warlord

End of fight: The attackers have caused more damage (5655 : 4560)!

Health (after battle): 16.669

Warlord captured : 20 Gold + 509 Gold bonus + 2 Experience
```

How can I use the "Health (after battle): HP" to create a loop?

I know what i want to do, I want to have it so if Health (after battle) = >8000 continue

but if <8000 to wait 5 minutes then check if >8000 to continue to loop through that block of code.

kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `while` loop example

```
import re

def letBattle():
  driver.get("https://randomtextrpg.com") # Starting Page
  time.sleep(1)

  driver.find_element_by_name("optionsearch").click() # Find Monsters
  time.sleep(1)

  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/div/div/button").click() # Attack Monster
  time.sleep(1)

  BattleReport = driver.find_element_by_id("reportResult") # Battle Report
  print (BattleReport.text)

  result = re.search(r'battle\):\s+([\d\.]+)', BattleReport.text).group(1) # 16.669
  result = result.replace('.', '') # 16669
  return int(result)


health = 8888 # dummy for first Battle

while health >= 8000:
  health = letBattle()
  if health <= 8000:
    print('health under 8000, sleeping 5 minutes...')
    time.sleep(300)
    # do your check
    # health = doCheckHealth()
  else:
    print('Continuing battle, health is: ' + health)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! is there anyway I could get in contact you for future advice?

Comment: you're welcome. you can contact me by leaving comment in any of my answer.

Comment: I'm having great difficulty finding the xpath for "health" on the website I'm using as a sandbox for this exercise. Whenever i inspect element, i get this `//*[@id="infobar"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/text()[5]` But when i convert to this `health = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[2]/div/div[1]/text()[5]")  # dummy for first Battle` I then get this error message " Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//div[2]/div/div[1]/text()[5]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element."

Comment: please create new post I will try to help

Comment: I have over on - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332077/trouble-finding-health-element  ... This is for the health check