# How to extract the text from the "Health" Element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I've been trying for hours to find the correct link to use in selenium for the HP value of this game.

To check yourself, I'll provide a user & password as belowed:

> Website : https://s3-en.bitefight.gameforge.com/user/login
>
> Username: testaccount111
>
> Password: python123

[image]

I've tried `health = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[2]/div/div[1]/text()[5]")`
but it gives errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the website `https://s3-en.bitefight.gameforge.com/user/login` to extract the text from *Health* element i.e. **8.460 / 21.500** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://s3-en.bitefight.gameforge.com/user/login")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='input' and @name='user']"))).send_keys("testaccount111")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='input' and @name='pass']").send_keys("python123")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='btn-small' and @value='Login']").click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='gold']//img[contains(@src,'/img/symbols')]")))
  health_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='gold']").get_attribute("textContent").splitlines()[5]
  print(health_text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
        8.460 / 21.500
  ```

Answer (score 2):

use below xpath to locate you element ( marked in image )

```
//img[@alt='Health']/preceding-sibling::text()[1]
```

but selenium doesn't allow you to locate an element using text node. alternative way is you can use javascript executor to evaluate the xpath.

I have below code reference in Java. please change as per python

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Object health= js.executeScript("var value = document.evaluate(\"//img[@alt='Health']/preceding-sibling::text()[1]\",document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null ); return value.stringValue;"); 
System.out.println(health.toString().trim());
```

OR

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gold']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String health= (String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[8].textContent", element);
System.out.println(health.trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

@NarendraR has good answer, in python the code to get result as `21500` is

```
health = driver.execute_script('''
  var value = document.evaluate("//img[@alt='Health']/preceding-sibling::text()[1]",document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null );
  return value.stringValue.split('/')[0].trim().replace('.', '');
''');
```

and for another method

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="gold"]')
health = re.search(r'(\d+\.\d+)\s+/', elem.text).group(1)
health = int(health.replace('.', ''))
```